# Url rewrite showing the real directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have read almost everything and in theory this should be correct. However the redirect shows the real directory in the url when I look for subdirectories.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myhost\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tool [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /tool/$1 [L]
```

If I go to http://myhost.com there is no problem, but when I try to go to http://myhost.com/subfolder/ this redirects to http://myhost.com/tool/subfolder/ instead of letting me see the content at the requested url http://myhost.com/subfolder/
Btw the content is loaded my problem is just the url bar.

In other words it works on the base folder but fails when I add something below.

1. **http://myhost.com  OK**
2. http://myhost.com/anything  OK it redirects to http://myhost.com/tool/anything (I don't want to see /tool/)
3. http://myhost.com/anything/ (trailing slash)  KO! it redirects to
   http://myhost.com/tool/http:/myhost.com/var/www/html/anything

Comment: Are there any other rules or directives in your htaccess file?

Comment: yes to many :) I created a virtual host because it was not possible to manage so many rules.